# I am trying to take input in specific form with separated spaces

Tags: java

I am trying to take input in specific form with first line containing number of queries and following lines each containing four integers separated by single spaces. I tried to write like the below Code but i am getting error "Cannot Find Symbol".
For example :-

```
1
1 1 3000 100000000
```

```
2
5 5 5000 100020000
7 7 2444 21412414124
```

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public void solveProb(int a, int d, int n, int x) {
        System.out.println(a+d + n + x);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int q = scan.nextInt();
        while (q > 0) {
            String[] s = scan.nextLine().split(" ");
            solveProb(Integer.parseInt(s[0]), Integer.parseInt(s[1]), Integer.parseInt(s[2]), Integer.parseInt(s[3]));
            q-- ;
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: `Interger.parseInt(String[1]),` I'm assuming this should be `Integer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `Integer.parseInt(String[0])` with `String[0]` when it should be using `s[0]` and so on with each of the others.  You call arrays using `variableName[index]`.

Additionally to call `solveProb` you either need to make it `public static void` or create an `Object` of class `Solution` with `Solution sol = new Solution()` and calling it with `sol.solveProb(VALUES)`

EDIT: To fix the `NumberFormatException` add `scan.nextLine();` before the `while` loop like so:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int q = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();
        while (q > 0) 
        {
            String[] s = scan.nextLine().split(" ");
            solveProb(Integer.parseInt(s[0]), Integer.parseInt(s[1]), Integer.parseInt(s[2]), Integer.parseInt(s[3]));
            q-- ;
        }     
    }

    public static void solveProb(int a, int d, int n, int x) 
    {
        System.out.println(a+d + n + x);
    }
```

You need to get to the next line after using `nextInt` since you are attempting to call `nextLine` and read it without going to the next line first.

Keep the inside of the loop the same, do not remove the other `nextLine`.

Comment: Are you still having issues with the symbol?  And what line

Comment: I edited it as per you told, but now i am getting NumberFormatException. Sorry i am new to java these are really confusing me.

Comment: @glitterfart1337 Check my edit, should fix that problem.

Comment: ```Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
 at Solution.main(Solution.java:15)```

Comment: See the recent edit and compare it to your current code, I've tested this code and it is working per your requirement.